# visual studio 2013 deploy a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I crack my head already, I need to deploy a project. I tried to use InstallShield, it create an msi file, and local installation has no errors, but then when I tried to launch the program it output "debug error". In my settings code generator -> runtime library set for Multi-threaded Debug DLL(/MDd). If I'll set it to Multi-threaded (/MT) it would not compile: "Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds"

[image]

[image]

Then I tried to use VS Installer project extension. It creates the msi and setup file, but after I install it, I can't find the .exe file and launch program. What I am doing wrong?

Folder with project files
![enter image description here][3]

Folder with exe file
![enter image description here][4]

Comment: Does your program use any external configuration files or other resources (e.g images, text files etc.) that are read by the program during its runtime? Are they placed in your project folder created by your IDE?

Comment: Yes, folder has all external files. I found another issue. I can't run application .exe file outside of the Visual Studio

Comment: It is only running using Local Windows Debugger and every time it's loading symbols. I don't know how to find head or tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!!!!!!!

1)Help to run .exe file, helped updating .uld file in the same directory as a exe file.

2)I used Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find all dll that it's need. And then I create a Setup Project using Wizard at the "Choose file to include" step I add every file and every library that it's depend on! Build->Install-> Then magic, and my application installed and running! Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

At the stage of creating the installer for your program, you have to put all the external files, libraries and resources, that your program needs in order to run correctly, in your program's working directory. When you run the program via Visual Studio, everything works fine since it can find the files, because, as you've mentioned, they are in the project folder, and the project folder is where Visual Studio is looking for them.

When you launch your program outside VS, the program can't find these files since it by default tries to locate them in the folder in which the .exe file being run is located. So, if you wan't to run program outside VS, you need to put all the files needed to your .exe's directory.

For the same reason, while creating your installer, you need to include all the files necessary in the installation target directory together with your .exe. Every installer creator lets you do that.

In general, if you cannot run your program outside any IDE, and you can run it within that IDE, it is a rule of thumb that you should first check if you have included all the necessary files/libraries/dll's/etc. in your program's working directory.

Comment: Make sense, but how do I find all library that it's need?

Comment: I saw in one article that you can change code generator -> runtime library  to Multi-threaded (/MT). that it cold help to fix library issue, but it does not work in my case. And I assume that exe file should be tight with library that it need. am I wrong?!

Comment: First, if you created or copied any files on your own into your project folder - i.e. any .txt files, images, configs etc., that your program opens and uses when it is running, you have to copy these files also to your exe's directory. When it comes to libraries, you can google or check in the docs if your particular library needs some dll's to run (also, if your program lacks DLL's, there is a high chance that the error message will tell you which DLL you need. Since it is not the case here, I suspect that you are missing some other files, not libraries, or at least, not only them).

Comment: there is no error while I run or debug the project!

Comment: txt file and images are in the same folder!

Comment: OK, just to make it clear, 'cause I'm not sure if we understand each other: please copy&paste here the full path of the folder, from which you run your program when you launch it outside VS, and then copy&paste the full path of the folder, where the files are located.